# If null return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I am trying to modify this query to return a row with '0' printed in either one or all of the rows when no data is returned. I've tried using ISNULL() but I am not getting anywhere.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
SA.DELETED,
PAT.VERSION, 
PAT.PATTERNDATE,
SA.AGENT_VERSION,
SCL.COMPUTER_NAME AS Computer_Name,
SCO.OPERATION_SYSTEM AS Operation_System,
dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SA.CREATION_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970 00:00:00') CREATION_DTTM,
dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SA.LAST_UPDATE_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970  00:00:00')  Lastupdatetime,
DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000,
'01-01-1970 00:00:00')LAST_SCAN_TIME,
PAT.PATTERNDATE AS Pattern_Date,
SCL.USER_NAME AS User_Name,
VSC.IP_ADDR1_TEXT AS IP_Add,
IM.NAME AS Group_Name

FROM ((((SEM_AGENT SA

INNER JOIN SEM_CLIENT SCL
ON ((SA.COMPUTER_ID=SCL.COMPUTER_ID) 
AND (SA.DOMAIN_ID=SCL.DOMAIN_ID)) 
AND (SA.GROUP_ID=SCL.GROUP_ID)) 

INNER JOIN SEM_COMPUTER   SCO
ON ((SA.COMPUTER_ID=SCO.COMPUTER_ID) 
AND (SA.DOMAIN_ID=SCO.DOMAIN_ID)) 
AND (SA.DELETED=SCO.DELETED))

INNER JOIN PATTERN PAT 
ON SA.PATTERN_IDX=PAT.PATTERN_IDX) 
INNER JOIN IDENTITY_MAP IM 
ON SCL.GROUP_ID=IM.ID) 

INNER JOIN V_SEM_COMPUTER VSC 
ON SCO.COMPUTER_ID=VSC.COMPUTER_ID 
AND SA.DELETED=0

WHERE PAT.Patterndate < (SELECT MAX(Patterndate) -2 FROM Pattern)
AND SCO.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%'
ORDER BY Computer_Name
```

Comment: Could you provide a slightly smaller example which has the same functionality as your example?

Comment: This is very difficult to read.

Comment: Do you know about [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)? Perhaps this could help.

Comment: This is SQL Server. This query was pre-generated by the software, I know its hard to read

Comment: Can you post your implementation of ISNULL(), I don't see why that wouldn't work

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, , if NO rows are returned, you are looking to a row with 0's?

Comment: Yes, I know about COALESCE. This is just difficult query to work with. @HolgerBrandt yes, that is what I am trying to do

Comment: This query may have been "pre-generated by the software", but you could take the time to clean it up before posting it here to make your question more readable; it would improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite - I went back and cleaned up the query the best I could. Let me know if this helps. I am still unable to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to returning a NULL row when no records is to

- Put your SQL in a CTE
- SELECT FROM your CTE with
- A Union of Default Values With an NOT EXISTS against your CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT "Computer Name".  ... 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT '', 0, 0, '' 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CTE)
ORDER BY 
     "Computer Name"
```

See [DEMO returns "null" record](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/2317) and [DEMO returns data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/2318). 
The difference between the two demos is `Where 1=2` and `Where 1=1` in the CTE

Comment: I tried this and received "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: @Ben You just need to move the order from the CTE to after the UNION.  See update

Comment: Thanks, I tried this update and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: I'm going to guess you added it to the UNION, but forgot to Remove it from the cte

Comment: I have it like this: with cte as
(SELECT <my query>
)  
SELECT * FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT '', 0, 0, '' 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CTE)
ORDER BY 
     "Computer Name"

Comment: @Ben can you create a SQLfiddle for it. Creating the DDL for 6 tables without being able to right click on the table and then selecting script table as -> Create to -> new query window... is a bit of a chore

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there are any rows with your conditions, and if not, select 0, otherwise, select your whole query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT"  
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID")  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER"  
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID")  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN"  
  ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP"  
  ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER"  
  ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"  
  AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0 
WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern) 
AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%' 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SELECT 0
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED" 
      ,"PATTERN"."VERSION"  
      ,"PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" 
      ,"SEM_AGENT"."AGENT_VERSION" 
      ,"SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_NAME" "Computer Name" 
      , "SEM_COMPUTER"."OPERATION_SYSTEM" "Operation System" 
      ,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."CREATION_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00')     
        CREATION_DTTM 
      , dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."LAST_UPDATE_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970  00:00:00')  Lastupdatetime 
      , DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00')"Last Scan Time" 
      , "PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" "Pattern Date" 
      , "SEM_CLIENT"."USER_NAME" "User Name" 
      , "V_SEM_COMPUTER"."IP_ADDR1_TEXT" "IP Address" 
      , "IDENTITY_MAP"."NAME" "Group Name" 
    FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT"  
      ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID")  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER"  
      ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID")  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN"  
      ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP"  
      ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER"  
      ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"  
      AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0 
    WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern) 
    AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%' 
    ORDER BY "Computer Name" 
END
```

If you know your inner joins will not change the number of results, then you can remove them from the first query for efficiency's sake.

If you didn't want to use @@ROWCOUNT, you could also use COUNT():

```
DECLARE @count INT

SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT"  
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID")  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER"  
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID")  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN"  
  ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP"  
  ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER"  
  ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"  
  AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0 
WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern) 
AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%' ) temp

IF @count = 0
SELECT 0
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED" 
      ,"PATTERN"."VERSION"  
      ,"PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" 
      ,"SEM_AGENT"."AGENT_VERSION" 
      ,"SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_NAME" "Computer Name" 
      , "SEM_COMPUTER"."OPERATION_SYSTEM" "Operation System" 
      ,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."CREATION_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00')     
        CREATION_DTTM 
      , dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."LAST_UPDATE_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970  00:00:00')  Lastupdatetime 
      , DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00')"Last Scan Time" 
      , "PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" "Pattern Date" 
      , "SEM_CLIENT"."USER_NAME" "User Name" 
      , "V_SEM_COMPUTER"."IP_ADDR1_TEXT" "IP Address" 
      , "IDENTITY_MAP"."NAME" "Group Name" 
    FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT"  
      ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID")  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER"  
      ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID")  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID"))  
      AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN"  
      ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP"  
      ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER"  
      ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"  
      AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0 
    WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern) 
    AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%' 
    ORDER BY "Computer Name" 
END
```

Comment: This returned "The column 'DOMAIN_ID' was specified multiple times for 'temp'."

Comment: That's because I said select * and your tables of columns with the same names - just changed the asterisk to a specific column or specifically list all of your columns with their table identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a query that returns 0 or more rows.  When it returns 0 rows, you want to include another row.

This adds computational complexity onto the query.  One way to do it is to union together the row you want, along with a flag that indicates where the row comes from.  Then, use a windows function to share that information among all rows, and use a where clause to filter the final rows:

```
select *
from (select t.*, sum(FromQ) over (partition by NULL) as numQ
      from (select *, 1 as FromQ
            from <query>
            union all
            select 0,0,0,0 . . . , 0 as FromQ
           ) t
      ) t
where numQ = 0 or numQ > 0 and FromQ <> 0
```

You might also just union the groups together, order by FromQ in reverse, and ignore the row in the application if it is not first.

Answer (score 0):

I broke it into three statements:

```
DECLARE @RecordCount int;

WITH Temp_CTE
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT EM_AGENT.DELETED
  ,PATTERN.VERSION 
  ,PATTERN.PATTERNDATE
  ,SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
  ,SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_NAME "Computer Name"
  ,SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM "Operation System"
  ,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SEM_AGENT.CREATION_TIME)/1000
    ,'01-01-1970 00:00:00') CREATION_DTTM
  , dateadd(s,convert(bigint,SEM_AGENT.LAST_UPDATE_TIME)/1000
    ,'01-01-1970  00:00:00') Lastupdatetime
  , DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000
    , '01-01-1970 00:00:00') "Last Scan Time"
  , PATTERN.PATTERNDATE "Pattern Date"
  , SEM_CLIENT.USER_NAME "User Name"
  , V_SEM_COMPUTER.IP_ADDR1_TEXT "IP Address"
  , IDENTITY_MAP.NAME "Group Name"
FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" 
INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) 
INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED"))
INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN" 
  ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") 
INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP" 
  ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") 
INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID" 
  AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0
WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern)
  AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%'
)
SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM Temp_CTE;

IF @RecordCount=0 THEN
  SELECT 0
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM Temp_CTE ORDER BY [Computer Name];
```

Comment: This one also returned "The column 'DOMAIN_ID' was specified multiple times for 'temp'."

Comment: @Ben Hmmm.  I don't DOMANIN_ID being returned.  However, I did see that I missed a comma in the `WITH Temp_CTE` field selection.  I amended my answer to fix that.